# How to create a Custom section in admin panel of umbraco 6?

Tags: umbraco

I am looking to develop a custom user section in admin panel of umbraco 6. 

This section can manage user details as well as admin approval. Any one know how to implement this?

Answer (score -1):

Apparently it is similar to [doing it in Umbraco 4](http://www.geckonewmedia.com/blog/2009/8/3/how-to-create-a-custom-section-in-umbraco-4)

But in Umbraco 6, instead of making the change to the `umbracoApp` table, you do the change in `Config/applications.config` file

**Update:**
For the tree nodes, I am still doing it [the old way](http://www.robertgray.net.au/posts/2011/5/creating-a-custom-content-tree-in-umbraco.aspx). Apparently in Umbraco 6 you can [use trees.config](http://www.theoutfield.net/blog/2012/07/creating-custom-applications-and-trees-in-umbraco-48plus), but I haven't tried it yet, I don't know much about it.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks aximili, its worked for me. So how can we create the child nodes under this main node?

Comment: That I'm not really sure because I'm still doing it the old way, see my updated comment

Answer (score -1):

I have written a blog post about this that should work in Umbraco 6.

The changes that have been made is that instead of changing in the tables you change in the config files. It is also possible to create the tables by code in C# combined with c# attributes.

http://marcus-abrahamsson.se/post/Custom-Section-in-Umbraco-Back-office

Comment: I've seen your post @Abris and did everything required (trees.config, applications.config, created file in umbraco/custom etc.) and still can't see the custom section to choose in my user permissions checkboxes in my CMS. Is there anything else which may be important?

Comment: this is why link only answers are frowned upon on SO