# How to create a custom section in Umbraco 6 and above?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco6

I need to create a custom section in umbraco 6. I've seen many references like,

http://adaodeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/01/create-new-custom-section-in-umbraco-48.html

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/46141-How-to-create-a-custom-BaseTree-tree

nothing works, I found a similar question in stackoverflow,

[How to create a Custom section in admin panel of umbraco 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810730/how-to-create-a-custom-section-in-admin-panel-of-umbraco-6)

but the link provided as an answer is not loading.

Many blogs says, the method of creating custom sections in older versions of umbraco. That doesn't work on umbraco 6.

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: FYI, Umbraco 7 would be completely different as they rebuilt the back-office to be an AngularJS SPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of creating the custom section is as same as the links you provided.

Check whether you are logged in as a root user, who created the umbraco project in the Users section.

Also, Check the UmbracoUsers table in your umbraco database. Because the newly created section will only visible to the root user only.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround of all this complexity: you can use usercontrol wrapper data type to place your layout inside of umbraco node. Here is a [link](http://nishantwork.wordpress.com/2012/09/20/umbraco-how-to-create-custom-data-type-in-umbraco-using-c/) and [link](http://www.nibble.be/?p=24).

Usercontrol wrapper datatype is designed to be an editor for some data, but it also enables developers to put whole admin pages inside of a node. (Probably this is what you need?)

I used it on umbraco v4.x but I am not sure if it is relevant for umbraco 6.

Comment: I don't want a usercontrol. I need entire section like media, content, etc.,