# Umbraco 6 cutom section set up not working

Tags: umbraco, config, app-config, umbraco6, custom-sections

I have made a custom section in my umbraco, set up trees.config and applications.config, added a file under umbraco/custom etc. as per here for example [How to create a Custom section in admin panel of umbraco 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810730/how-to-create-a-custom-section-in-admin-panel-of-umbraco-6/16194338)

trees.config:

```
<add application="custom" alias="custom" title="custom" assembly="CustomSection" type="Trees.LoadCustomTree" silent="false" initialize="true" iconClosed=".sprTreeFolder" iconOpen=".sprTreeFolder_o" action="" sortOrder="0" />
```

applications.config

```
<add alias="custom" name="custom" icon="custom.gif" sortOrder="10" />
```

Still I cannot see my custom section in my user edit screen.

Is there anything I need to set up/ watch out?

Thanks

Comment: Try to restart your website (new ddls, touch webconfig or iisreset).. Umbraco reads these config on startup.

Comment: No, it's not that. Tried it multiple times @MortenOC

Comment: I had this issue and realised after creating the section also need to give your User access to it

Comment: @BenStephens yes, this is what I couldn't do because the section didn't appear on users permission lists. However I added an entry into the database directly and relogged. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

Under certain circumstances (from memory, I think it happens if you change the name of your default Umbraco administrator user) your application won't appear in the permissions list in the Umbraco user manager.

You can fix this by manually creating an entry in the umbracoUser table to give permission to your administrator. Once this has been done, the option will appear for all of your users.

Comment: This is what I actually did and it fixed the problem as nothing. Thanks anyway @Chris